# How to get a block at an offset in the IO.foreach loop in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I'm using the IO.foreach loop to find a string using regular expressions. I want to append the next block (next line) to the file_names list. How can I do that?

```
file_names = [""]                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
IO.foreach("a.txt") { |block|                                                                                                                         
  if block =~ /^file_names*/                                                                                              
    dir = # get the next block                                                                                                                                                                                           
    file_names.append(dir)                                                                                      
  end                                                                                                                    

}
```

---

Actually my input looks like this:

```
file_names[174]:                                                                                                         
           name: "vector"                                                                                                
      dir_index: 1                                                                                                       
       mod_time: 0x00000000                                                                                              
         length: 0x00000000                                                                                              
file_names[175]:                                                                                                         
           name: "stl_bvector.h"                                                                                         
      dir_index: 2                                                                                                       
       mod_time: 0x00000000                                                                                              
         length: 0x00000000
```

I have a list of file_names, and I want to capture each of the name, dir_index, mod_time and length properties and put them into the files_names array index according to the file_names index in the text.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific about your input format? Just the next line or until another delimiter? As a note `/file_names*/` matches `"file_name"`, `"some kind of file_name"` and `"file_namessssssssssss"`.

Comment: You're right. It should be /^file_names*/ instead. Check out my edit for an elaboration.

Comment: In Ruby it's actually `/\Afile_names/` where `\A` anchors to the beginning of string, `^` at the beginning of a line. `*` means "zero or more of character" which doesn't appear to be what you mean. You seem to be using it as "more stuff", which it isn't.

Comment: Another thing to node here is that `file_names = [""]` initializes your array with an empty string already in it. That's probably a mistake, as it should be an empty array: `file_names = [ ]`. You can append as necessary without the empty string.

Comment: @tadman. It's not. file_names indexing in the text starts from 1

Comment: Everything in Ruby, like most programming languages, indexes from zero. You should just accept that and either add or subtract one as necessary when manipulating that array. Sticking in a placeholder causes all kinds of trouble from an architectural perspective.

Comment: No it doesn't. It works for what I'm doing.

Comment: What does "...and put them into the files_names array index according to the file_names index in the text." mean? When giving an example you need to show the desired return value (as a Ruby object).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`#each_cons`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons) to get the value of the next 4 rows from the text file:

```
files = IO.foreach("text.txt").each_cons(5).with_object([]) do |block, o|
  if block[0] =~ /file_names.*/
    o << block[1..4].map{|e| e.split(':')[1]}
  end
end

puts files
#=> "vector"                                                                                                
#    1                                                                                                       
#    0x00000000                                                                                              
#    0x00000000                                                                                              
#    "stl_bvector.h"                                                                                         
#    2                                                                                                       
#    0x00000000                                                                                              
#    0x00000000
```

Keep in mind that the `files` array contains subarrays of 4 elements. If the `:` symbol occurs later in the lines, you could replace the third line of my code with this:

```
o << block[1..4].map{ |e| e.partition(':').last.strip}
```

I also added `#strip` in case you want to remove the whitespaces around the values. With this line changed, the actual array will look something like this:

```
p files
#=>[["\"vector\"", "1", "0x00000000", "0x00000000"], ["\"stl_bvector.h\"", "2", "0x00000000", "0x00000000"]]
```

(the values don't contain the `\` escape character, that's just the way `#p` shows it).

Another option, if you know the pattern `1 filename, 4 values` will be persistent through the entire text file and the textfile always starts with a filename, you can replace `#each_cons` with [`#each_slice`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/each_slice) and remove the regex completely, this will also speed up the entire process:

```
IO.foreach("text.txt").each_slice(5).with_object([]) do |block, o|
  o << block[1..4].map{ |e| e.partition(':').last.strip }
end
```

Answer (score 1):

It's actually pretty easy to carve up a series of lines based on a pattern using [`slice_before`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_before):

```
File.readlines("data.txt").slice_before(/\Afile_names/)
```

Now you have an array of arrays that looks like:

```
[
  [
    "file_names[174]:\n",
    "           name: \"vector\"\n",
    "      dir_index: 1\n",
    "       mod_time: 0x00000000\n",
    "         length: 0x00000000\n"
  ],
  [
    "file_names[175]:\n",
    "           name: \"stl_bvector.h\"\n",
    "      dir_index: 2\n",
    "       mod_time: 0x00000000\n",
    "         length: 0x00000000"
  ]
]
```

Each of these groups could be transformed further, like for example into a Ruby Hash using those keys.

Comment: I suggest using`IO::foreach`, which, without a block, returns an enumerator, to avoid the creation of a temporary array.

Comment: @CarySwoveland There's also `File.each_line` which might read better.

Comment: I'm not aware of `File.each_line`. A Rail's method?

Comment: @CarySwoveland It's actually [`IO#each_line`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/IO.html#method-i-each_line) which `File` inherits from. It may in fact be related to `foreach`, but that method is just awkwardly named.

Comment: I had looked in `IO`, but for a class method, not an instance method. You'd have to write something like `f = File.new("testfile"); f.each_line {...}; f.close`.